# Mouse scroll wheel does not work for ubuntu 12.04 running under Hyper-V for Windows 8 Pro

Tags: 12.04, windows-8, virtualization, mouse-wheel

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 lts on a Hyper-V virtual machine (MS Windows 8 Pro) and I need some help with the mouse driver.

The mouse responds fine in general: the cursor's moving, left/right click works OK and also when I press the wheel windows are changing and tabs are closing.

Everything EXCEPT using the scroll wheel.  Then nothing happens.

Can someone guide me how to solve this? Thanks!